# How to create array for possible probability (combinations) for given number in php

Tags: php, discrete-mathematics

I am having **mathematics** oriented question.Here i like to get the all possible combinations
and looking to store in array.

For example:-

```
1 digit = 10 (0,1,2,3,....9) 
2 digit = 100 (00,01,02,03,...)
```

I am having formula to find number of possibilities i.e `10^n -1`.But i don't know how can i get the values.

```
function get_combinations(5){
//10^5 -1 = 99999 values 

}
```

## the function result should be

**00000,00001,00010,00100,....**

in array

## not like

**0,1,2,....00,01,03,...99999**

EDIT

I also like to  mix some **alphabets** with the number

results like

**0000a,000a1,000z1,00001,00000,....**

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can count from 0 to 10^5 -1 and add leading zeros if necessary.

Comment: I feel that putting everything in an array is the wrong solution here. You will probably use the array values *one at a time*, so why precalculate them and not just simply generate them inside a loop as needed?

Comment: `2 digit = 99 (00,01,02,03,...)` <-- why's that? Which number is not counted in? I see that `00` is counted, I guess `99` is also counted, so there are 100 combinations, not 99.

Comment: Not to be funny but isn't the answer simply your destination number -1 for example 10-1 or 100-1?? With padded zeroes? Why do you need an array for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$n = ???;
$array = range(0, pow(10, $n)-1);
```

---

yes, there is no integer start with `zero`

so, dun bother to construct an array start with leading `zero`,
when you need to output [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) can be applied

---

```
function get_combinations($n)
{
  return range(0, pow(10, $n)-1);
}

$array = get_combinations(5);
$pad   = strlen(max($array));

// to output
echo str_pad($array[0], $pad, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: i need results in array .can you give the suggestion

Comment: the results is already in array ... not quite sure what is still missing?

Comment: I need one more help. I like to mix up alphabets with the numbers .please check my edit.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = array();
$count = pow(10,$x);
for ($i = 0, $i < $count, $i++) {
  $result[] = str_repeat('0', $x - strlen($i)) . $i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an integer that is `0000` because that is just `0`.

**To get all numbers from 0 to 9 use** [`the range() function`](http://php.net/range):

```
$array = range(0,9); // array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

And alike for bigger numbers.

If you want them as strings use sprintf or related to reformat that array.

Or just use a `for(` loop :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_combinations($exp){

    $max = pow(10, $exp) - 1;

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $max; $i++) $comb[] = str_pad($i, $exp, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    return $comb;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$n = 3;
function format($x) {
    global $n;
    return sprintf("%0${n}d", $x);
}
$arr = array_map('format', range(0, pow(10,$n)-1));
```